# UIWebview show previous loaded content for brief

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am loading html string with **loadHTMLString** method in `UIWebView` in `UICollectionViewCell`  and reuse that cell.but `UIWebview` showing previous loaded content for brief and after that load new content.

anyone have any idea about this??

Answer (score 1):

Load the Webview in following method of `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: not working still same issue is there ,display previous content for brief.

Comment: It might be due to it takes some time to load the content of new url.... i mean it must be network lag

Comment: can you please share the collection view delegate method that you are using to load html?

Answer (score 0):

In your cellforitem method, first reset webview content with following code:

[cell.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];

after this line , write code to load your new url or new data.